# Luggage transfer at Heathrow: Jet Airways to Air Canada

Tags: luggage, lhr, air-canada, jet-airways

I'm traveling from Bangalore, India to Ottawa, Canada on three different flights. My flight plan is as follows: BLR-DELHI-LHR(London)-YOW(Ottawa).

- BLR to Delhi - Jet Airways
- Delhi to LHR (London) - Air India
- LHR to YOW (Ottawa) - Air Canada

All the tickets are under one ticket number. Will my check-in luggage be transferred to other airline till my destination or do I need to check out and re-check in.

It is not possible for me to check out and re-check-in in London because my layover time is only 2hrs and 30mins.

So if I ask the check-in counter in Bangalore to give my checked-in luggage at YOW (Ottawa), will they agree to that? Please confirm.

Comment: Call/email to all three airway to find the answer

Comment: Yes, they most likely will. I flew the LHR-YOW leg where I was in transit in LHR, and the bags were checked throughout. To be ABSOLUTELY certain, make sure they give you a bag tag that shows YOW on it. That means its checked in all the way.

Answer (score 1):

The three flights have been purchased as one ticket. Your bags will be checked through to your final destination (Ottawa).

For informational purposes, if you enter a port in Canada that is not your final destination in Canada, you would have to clear customs at the first point of entry in Canada. In your case, Ottawa is your first port of entry in to Canada as well as your final destination so this does not apply to you.